# split H1 in 2 colors

Tags: html, css

I have to apply a different color to just a part of my main heading.
It is just one word.

```
<h1>HEA<span class="red">DING</span></h1>
```

That's what I have now, but I'm concerned about my code being as semantically correct as possible. Is there any more correct way to do this?

Comment: It's the correct way. Was your question related to the validation status of your HTML? If yes, for further questions like this one - check [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)

Comment: @ElyasAktaou: span is non-semantic element (like a div), from the SEO-view it seems like a there is no span. For splitting headline due to colors it´s the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN | Heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) the permitted content of heading elements is [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) and `<span>` tag belongs to the category phrasing content.

**EDIT**

It will not have any negative effect on your SEO. A `<span>` tag is not a semantic markup.